# How to display all row in ResultSet using XML DOM, jsp and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, jsp

```
    in database
```

[image]

when i fetch the data from database onchange of drop down, actually this is the real time scenario, am using jsp  you can integrate with any type of frame works ( in .java files ), concept is same.

```
if i run this code it show the first row information 

<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    var keys=document.dummy.sele.value
    var urls="db_fetch.jsp?ok="+keys
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
    var some=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empno")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empaddr")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",urls,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="dummy">
    <select name="sele" onchange="loadXMLDoc()">
    <option>value</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="101">101</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    id: <span id="a"></span><br>
    name: <span id="b"></span><br>
    address: <span id="c"></span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

db_fetch.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%

response.setContentType("text/xml");
String sn=request.getParameter("ok");
int i=Integer.parseInt(sn);

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@www.java4s.com:1521:XE","system","admin");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from emp where empno="+i);
if(rs.next())
{

out.println("<emp>");
out.println("<empno>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</empno>");
out.println("<empname>"+rs.getString(2)+"</empname>");
out.println("<empaddr>"+rs.getString(3)+"</empaddr>");
out.println("</emp>");

}

rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();

%>
```

above code result is

[image]

i need a result as

id 100,

name java4s

address usa

id 100,

name php4s

address usa

id 100,

name visa4s

address usa

id 100,

name usa4s

address usa

i think code may change in here

```
{
    var some=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empno")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empaddr")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
```

in database address column is there

Comment: Are you trying to basically print the above table into your page?

Comment: the above code display the first row in result set but i need a all row in result set

Comment: i need a output linke this 'id 100, name java4s, address usa:(\n)   id 100, name php4s, address usa: (\n)id 100, name vish4s address usa:(\n)id 100, name usa4s address usa

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a while loop to print all ResultSet Data.

your empno is not  a `unique` column type, so basically you need other way to identify the second row. such as count,empname and etc...

```
int count=0;
while(rs.next()){
  count++;
  if(count!=2)return;//display only the second row
  //if(!"php4s".equals(rs.getString(2)))return;//display only the php4s row
  out.println("<emp>");
  out.println("<empno>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</empno>");
  out.println("<empname>"+rs.getString(2)+"</empname>");
  out.println("<empaddr>"+rs.getString(3)+"</empaddr>");
  out.println("</emp>");

}
```

Comment: the above code display the first row in result set but i need a all row in result set

Comment: 'id 100,

name php4s

address usa'id 100,

name java4s

address usa,id 100, 

name vish4s

address usa id 100,

name usa4s

address usa

Comment: i need a output linke this 'id 100, name java4s, address usa:(\n)   id 100, name php4s, address usa: (\n)id 100, name vish4s address usa:(\n)id 100, name usa4s address usa

Comment: i think here we need to chage  var some=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empno")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML=some.getElementsByTagName("empaddr")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Comment: Yes, you need to change your code in the `ajax callback zone`.Use for loop to display and get data.